# Get version of specific module in multi module maven project

Tags: maven, maven-3, multi-module

I have a multiple maven module project. I need to retrieve a module's current version.

```
Parent Pom (2.4.0)
|- module1 1.5.0
|- module2 1.3.4
|- module3 1.2.5
```

Get version of `module2` would return `1.3.4`.

FYI: `module1` maybe a dependency of `module2`.

Found one way of doing it was

```
mvn depedency:tree -X |  awk '/module1/ {split($0, a, ":"); if (a[4]) {print a[4]; exit}}'
```

Would prefer a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of solution, but they're all based on the same logic:

`mvn -f model2 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout`

With `-f model2` or `-f model2/pom.xml` you specify the path to the pom.xml

With `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate` you call the [evaluate goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html) of the maven-help-plugin. If the pom already has a locked version on this plugin, you can simply use `help:evaluate`

With `-Dexpression=project.version` you specify what you want to know. In case it starts with project, you're following the xml structure of the pom.

With `-q` you suppress the output logging as handled by the logging framework of Maven.

But that would also suppress the result of the evaluate goal too. Hence by using `-DforceStdout` the result will be visible, because it bypasses the logging framework.

Comment: thanks! this is much cleaner way of doing it. Used this as bash example shown on https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html to assign to variable then either echo it out or use the variable further. Cheers!